# Fatal exception when I restart my app after it's been killed (android)

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

When I restart my app after its been killed (after an hour or so by android or if I kill it via task killer), the app crashes with the following message:

> 10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ com.test.testapp /com.test.testapp.TestingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.test.testapp.TestingActivity.onCreate(TestingActivity.java:178)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   10-23 09:07:41.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

I have a timer in that activity and I thought maybe it had something to do with that thread but even if I remove the timer it still crashes. I really can't figure out what's wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's at line 178 of TestingActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will reclaim memory. You need to check it's not null. It says which line is complaining too

Comment: It seems to have to do with the activity trying to access a global variable. Seems I have to find a way around that. But my question now is, is there any way to make the app start from the main screen when it's been killed?

Comment: check if the problem variables are null. If true finish and start your mianscreen

Comment: Thanks A LOT for the help. Works now. Can't believed I missed that. Anyway, thanks for the help. Really appreciate it